# Is is possible to build a cms without using any scripting language on the serverside?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to know if there is a way to build a CMS using no scripting language on the serverside, i.e. only use server to store data?

Comment: If there would be a "CMS" that has a build-in generator for generating a HTML-framework that you can then upload, you would not have a problem with security because there would be no online backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically - yes, but you'll not be able to make it secured.

Comment: that's what been bugging me.  Is there really no way to make it secure?

Comment: Huh, why not? HTTP basic or digest auth with SSL sounds pretty good to me?

Comment: @roe: it strongly depends on how you propose to store data. If it is really **cms** built using javascript with some sort of dbms on the server (which fits the requirement) - then you'll not be able to protect content.

Comment: The storing part is definitely a problem, but I'd wager a bet there are plug-ins for various web servers which will heed, for example, .htaccess requirements. This ought to work around the "no server side scripts" requirement. You'll need a predefined set of 'sercured' areas, and a predefined set of users and what they're allowed to see. If your definition of CMS includes modifying these settings, then maybe you're right. Last way out it still to write a plugin to the web server, which isn't technically a 'script'.

Comment: @roe: well, I agree that basic auth can help in some cases, but the question is too vague to discuss ;-)

Comment: @zerkms; no argument on the vagueness ... :) I also edited my previous comment to add a note on user management.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it depends on what you define as a CMS. If you just want user authentication, displaying web pages, then this is quite possible to do with a static-serving web server (Assuming it supports authentication mechanisms and SSL).

If you want stuff to be searchable, you'll need SOMETHING server side doing the indexing (the actual search can still be done client side by downloading relevant index files). Or tap into Google, but this only works if you have no security requirements.

If you want to be able to upload stuff, your server needs to handle this as well.

Without specifying exactly what you're looking for, there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: it's the comments part that's bugging me.  If users want to comment, how can i get those comments and show them on a static data hosting server...

Comment: @the_archer Outsourcing :) Find a third-party comment service that allows to insert comments in your site with some JavaScript code.

Comment: @the_archer; if you can solve the storing part, you can get files using javascript, e.g. starting at comment-0, comment-1, comment-2, until there's a 404, and then you're good. The storing part is more tricky, as you might end up in race conditions, so you need a store function which won't overwrite files, and try again with a higher number if you get a collision.

Comment: the problem is that I want to have access to those comments as data to be manipulated, that's why I'm not using disqus/intense debate etc...

Comment: @the_archer; I don't see the problem? You want to, as an admin manipulate the comments? Just log on to the server and change the files?

Answer (score 2):

CMS stands for "Content Management System". It's basically an organized way to store your content, with some productivity tools (UI, workflows, ...)

Your server can be seen as a CMS :

- The http server provides various authentication schemes
- The http server provides encrypting (via https)
- The filesystem allows you to create, read, update and delete files.
- The filesystem provides a way to manage user (and even groups) rights on these files.
- The filesystem allows you to organize your files in folders
- The filesystem even allows you to reference files in several folders (via symlinks)

So yes, you can use your server as a CMS. All you have to do is define rules for your content management :

- folders organisation
- files naming conventions
- files format conventions
- ...